# ReactiveUI Command concurrency (WebClient)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, reactiveui

I'm using the latest prerelease of RxUI 8, but I think this would happen in prior versions.

I have defined this ReactiveCommand in my WPF application:

```
GetWebsiteCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(DownloadString);

private async Task<string> DownloadString()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.es");
    }
}
```

When the command is executed, the following exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException' at System.Reactive.Core.dll: The
>   calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread
>   owns it

Why is this happening? I'm not creating any new thread!

This is the Stack Trace:

> System.InvalidOperationException' at System.Reactive.Core.dll: The
>   calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread
>   owns it

```
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.get_Command()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateCanExecute()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteChangedEventManager.HandlerSink.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged()
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`2.<.ctor>b__9_5(Boolean _)
   at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive()
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.CombineLatest`3._.S.OnNext(TSecond value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.RefCount`1._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive()
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Concat`1._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.SafeObserver`1.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver`1.Dispatch(ICancelable cancel)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.<>c.<ScheduleLongRunning>b__72_0(Action`1 a, ICancelable c)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<ScheduleLongRunning>b__0(Object arg)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<StartThread>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: You are not creating any new thread? Maybe you are not familiar with the concept of Task. Read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) for information

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto. No, I'm not creating any new Thread. Where am I creating a Thread? For what I know, a Task DOES NOT involve the creation of any Thread. Do you know if WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync method is running the task on a different thread?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you, please, tell me whether Task.FromResult( () => 1) runs on a new Thread? Stop downvoting without a reason, please, and start giving useful answers. Otherwise, let other people do.

Comment: @SuperJMN do you have a stack trace for the exception? I suspect something else is triggering this as a result of the command execution. The reactive command will guarantee output is delivered via `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`, so I'm guessing there's something else going on here...

Comment: @me-- Please, check the OP. I've added the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace, you are passing a `canExecute` pipeline into the command. For any pipeline you provide, you are responsible for ensuring it ticks on the correct thread. If it ticks on a background thread, the commands `CanExecute` event will tick on that same thread and the UI will therefore attempt to update the `IsEnabled` property on the associated `Button` from the wrong thread.

So you likely need to add an `ObserveOn` call against your `canExecute` pipeline.

UPDATE: answered [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1498).

Comment: Thank you, Kent! But I'm not passing any CanExecute pipeline. The Command is created with the line `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(DownloadString);` So I'm only passing the Task. Can you, please, run the code? With those simple lines you will be able to reproduce the problem.